# Login/Log Out sample application is Struts 2 problem

Tags: ajax, struts2

Login/Log Out sample application is Struts 2

what are the additional technologies used in order to

make a logged-out user unable to login back by using

back button of the browser ?

please give the sample code also

when using struts 2 and its session invalidation is not giving the above mentioned
result.

Comment: When you hit back and then refresh, is the user still logged in?

Comment: when i hit back and then refresh, the user is still logged in

Answer (score 0):

use this scriptlet

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
```

Comment: - I had already added this scriptlet earlier. If we use this scriptlet and when the user logged out and clicks on the back button of the browser, browser will display the page as "Web page has expired". Instead of this i want to redirect the page to "login page"

Comment: @Sankar have you put the following at the top of your page              <%if(session.getAttribute("currentUser") == null){%>                             <jsp:forward page="Logout.jsp"/>
<%}%>